# Uncertainty vs Cause and Effect

Tags: karma, future, cause-and-effect, uncertainty

Isn't **uncertainty** and **cause and effect** conflict each other ? Did Lord Buddha teach about uncertainty ? (Ven. Ajahn Brahma thero on uncertainty - [Life is a series of unexpected events](https://youtu.be/B30aqzhP5mc) )

**My understanding:** To the Buddha, life is not uncertain. Because Lord Buddha knew his and other people's past karma. He knew almost everything about the universe. So, He had ability to predict the future. But for us, We don't have that knowledge. So, Life is uncertain to us.

Comment: Here are two related questions/answers perhaps you would find interesting: https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/30590/buddhist-perspective-uncertainty and https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/36960/is-uncertainty-incompatible-with-the-doctrine-of-emptiness

Comment: The subject of universe is **infinite**. It's impossible to analize **all** past events, karma of **all** living species and **all** current situations for anyone. Because of that, Life is uncertain. Am I correct ?

Comment: Buddha didn't answered to the question "*When was the beginning of samsara ?*". To predict the future, We have to consider karmas from beginning of samsara to current moment.

Answer (score 1):

Uncertainty occurs because of causes. There is no difference between uncertainty and cause & effect.

> *Death is certain, life is uncertain: maranam niyatam, jivitam aniyatam*
>
> *It disintegrates, monk, that is why it’s called ‘the world’: lujjatīti kho, bhikkhu, tasmā lokoti vuccatī*
>
> *'Many are the [possible] causes of my death. A snake might bite me, a scorpion might sting me, a centipede might bite me. That would be how my death would come about. That would be an obstruction for me. Stumbling, I might fall; my food, digested, might trouble me; my bile might be provoked, my phlegm... piercing wind forces [in the body] might be provoked. That would be how my death would come about.*